# Django ModelForm Date Validation

Tags: django, forms, validation, model

With the default DateField() validation, there are a couple different formats you can use to insert the month, day, and year.  However, I need to allow the user to enter just the year OR the month, day, and year.

For instance, in the same field, you could insert '5/10/2003' or '2003' and the validation would pass.  Also, if '2003' was inserted, would it just have to be defaulted to '1/1/2003' (or something similar) or is there a better way to do this?

Finally, can this be done in the model by overriding the clean() method so that I don't have to reuse the code across multiple forms? ie:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    start_date = models.DateField()
    ## other fields

    def clean(self):
        # clean other fields as normal

        # override start_date
```

Or should it look something like this:

```
def validate_date(value):
    """ Validate date to allow YYYY """
    ## Raise error on Validation fail

class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    start_date = models.DateField()
    ## other fields

    def clean(self):
        # clean other fields as normal

        # override start_date
```

Comment: Not sure if this works, but worth a shot - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-DATE_FORMAT change the `DATE_FORMAT` settings to what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation on creating custom form fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#creating-custom-fields) is sparse, but it's possible.

```
from django import forms


class MonthDateYearOrYearField(forms.DateField):
    def clean(self, value):
        date_length = len(value)

        if date_length == 4:  # 2003
            value = '1/1/{year}'.format(year=value)
        elif 8 <= date_length <= 10:  # 5/10/2003, 05/10/2003, 5/9/2009
            pass
        else:
            raise forms.ValidationError('date format must be "MM/DD/YYYY" or "YYYY"')

        return super(MonthDateYearOrYearField, self).clean(value)

class Project(forms.Form):
    start_date = MonthDateYearOrYearField()
```

The `elif` conditional probably needs some work, but you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks, I'll definitely give it a try when I get back to work! Seems like it's what I was looking for though